# Mobile - Youtube api copyrighted video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are developing an application that allows the user to search through the youtube api and reproduce a video.

The issue that we are experiencing is that we are trying to filter out all non playable videos, for example like vevo which are not embeddable.

We are using the api params:

```
  videoEmbeddable: 'true',
  safeSearch: 'strict',
  videoSyndicated: 'true'
```

These filters should leave out all videos with any type of restriction.
The problem is that we are getting some videos filtered, and supposed to be safe to display, but whenever we try to display them, for a good amount of videos we get the message that either the video is not playable or the message that the video contains copyrighted material.
Seems like the filters are not working out as expected.

"This video contains content from SME. It is restricted to playback on certain sites."

I have no issue with some videos being restricted, but we're just trying to find a way to filter those out from the query.

Any ideas, or information on how to filter out those videos?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a number of bug reports that seem similar to your issue: See here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7348 and https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6346 for examples. Unfortunately, none of these seem to have workarounds or to have made any progress. It may be that you have to filter the returned results manually until the API is fixed.

Comment: I'd love to do that, the issue is that there is no information that allows me to do the filtering.
For most of the videos seems that the values are according to the search params, although after that still not playable embedded.

Comment: You could call Videos:List with a comma delimited list of the IDs which your search returns and specify part as `status`. You can then check `status.embeddable` for each video. Not very clean though! Also, have you specified `type` as `video` in your call? Without this the videoEmbeddable field is ignored. (Although I think it would throw an error anyway if the type was missing).

Comment: Do you have an example call which can be used to replicate your problem. Someone may be able to look at this and give you more feedback.

Comment: Let me try to add an example to the question.
@theduck regarding the search Im already specifying video as type. Also I have already done the video/list with the list of ids, the issue is that for the ids not playable the embeddable returns true.